# Which mode is best for a special configuration file, specifically logstash

Tags: major-mode

I'm using [logstash](https://www.elastic.co/products/logstash) and its configuration file (documented [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/configuration.html)) looks like this:

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/some/path/to/file"
    option => 1
  }
}
filter {
  if [var] == "string" {
    action {
      array_option => [ "val1", "val2", "val3" ]
      object_option => {
        str_option => "string"
      }
    }
  }
}
# this is a comment
output {
  stdout
}
```

I'm looking for a helpful emacs mode that works well with files like this. The `conf-mode` does good highlighting, but I can't get it to indent properly. Any suggestions?

Comment: This looks very similar to Puppet configuration files, or maybe Ruby in general. What if you try any of those modes (it probably won't cover it 100%, but should be very close).

Comment: You're right. It is actually ruby. `ruby-mode` works perfectly. Thnx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although `ruby-mode` works pretty well, there were some problems. After trying several other modes, I found this [`json-mode`](https://github.com/joshwnj/json-mode) to work perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Technically it's a custom grammar: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21442715/what-is-the-format-of-logstash-config-file

This is supposed to be just for logstash configs: https://github.com/Wilfred/logstash-conf.el

I came across this answer looking for something for Atom. Nothing exists as far as I can tell, but similarly the Ruby and JSON modes in Atom do an OK job of highlighting and indenting (auto-indent also works).